# How to eliminate duplicate characters

Tags: c

Here is an algorithm to eliminate sequence of the same character and replace them with one character, but it doesn't work. Some help please?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main ()
{
char ch[100],ch1[100]="",ch2[100];
int i;

gets(ch);

i=0;

while(i<strlen(ch)-1)
{
    if(ch[i]==ch[i+1])
    {

        strncpy(ch1,ch,i);

        strcat(ch1,ch+i+1);

        sprintf(ch,"%s",ch1);
    }
    else 
     i++;

}

puts(ch);

return 1;
}
```

Comment: “It doesn't work” is not an error description. What happens and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: you shall not use `gets`. if `i` is smaller than `strlen(ch)`, `strncpy(ch1,ch,i);` will not add a terminating `'\0'` to `ch1`, which will make `strcat(ch1,ch+i+1);` invoking undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is here:

```
strncpy(ch1,ch,i);
```

The `strncpy` function doesn't add a NULL termination character if it doesn't find one in the first `i` characters of `ch`.  The first time through the loop is fine since `ch1` is initialized, however an subsequent iterations it contains whatever it last had.  So when you get to `strcat`, it appends to what was previously there.

After the call to `strncpy`, you need to add the NULL terminator yourself:

```
strncpy(ch1,ch,i);
ch1[i] = '\0';
```

Also, never use `gets`.  It doesn't do proper bounds checking.  Instead, use `fgets`:

```
fgets(ch, sizeof(ch), stdin);
```